# Can I return 404 in nginx when the URL contains a file extension?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm new to nginx and need to modify an application's nginx configuration file to always return a 404 if the URL contains a file extension. My nginx.conf file is as follows:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            expires 5m;
        }

        location /appsettings.json {
            expires 5m;
        }

        location /version.json {
            expires 5m;
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ext with the extension you wish to ban:

```
location ~ \.ext$ {
  return 404;
}
```

If you want to ban all extensions (anything with a dot really):

```
location ~ \. {
  return 404;
}
```